# PHP/Mysql Calendar

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, key

Sorry for my poor english.

I would like to use the "on duplicate key update" but I do not know how to.

My MySQL database is alike :

```
id (primary key | autoincrement), id_hostel, date, allotement
```

My MySQL query :

```
insert into table (id_hostel, datebvj, allotement) VALUES
('1','09/05/2012','7'), ('1','10/05/2012','5'),
('1','11/05/2012','6')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE allotement=VALUES(allotement)
```

allotement means rooms

The problem : This query makes an insert query even if there is already a data in the database.

I would like the query to run good.

Any suggestion ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you determine whether the record to be inserted is the "same" as an existing record?  Is it if the `id_hostel` is the same?

Comment: As a side note, have you considered using `REPLACE INTO`?

Comment: I will consider it... Thank you Leonard !

Answer (score 1):

An 'on duplicate' will only convert into an update if the insert would result in a duplicate record being created, where duplicate means a unique/primary key index would be violated.

Given your table structure, you'd have to insert a duplicate `id` field to trigger the conversion. None of your other fields have unique keys, and your insert statement is not inserting an id value, so there is no way to trigger the insert->update switch.

Comment: The id_hostel goes from 1 to 3 (number of hostels).
Both The date AND id_hostel determine whether the record is inserted or not.

Comment: I changed the query by :
insert into table (id_hostel, datebvj, allotement) VALUES ('1','09/05/2012','7'), ('1','10/05/2012','5'), ('1','11/05/2012','6') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_hostel=VALUES(id_hostel)
but it does not work !

Comment: That's because `id_hostel` is not a unique key. The only unique key in your table is the `id` field, and you're not inserting anything into that, letting mysql generate its own key value, preventing there ever being a collision, causing an update

Comment: I should make the id_hostel become a primary key ?

Comment: No idea - only you can make that decision, but an 'on duplicate key' type query will ONLY do an update if a unique key would be violated by inserting the new data. However you rearrange your tables to make that happen is up to you.

Comment: I tried many things but The problem is still here.

My new database :
id_hostel, date, room (primary key)

My Query that does not work :
insert into table (id_hostel, datebvj, room) VALUES ('1','09/05/2012','6') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE room=VALUES(room)

Need some help please.